# ошибка со Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger

подключил =>
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

написал => [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

написал => [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

запустил и написал =>[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получил => [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чём может быть проблема, как решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего ошибка в ***RoutePrefix***, попробуйте сделать его пустым
зы. чтобы проверить создал он json или нет, нужно перейти по пути файла
https://localhost:44365/swagger/v1/swagger.json

```
   public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        // Регистрация
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Title = "My Title App",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "My Title App description"
            });

            // Указываем путь к комментариям
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlFile );
        });

        ...
   }
```

...

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Включаем генерацию json'a
        app.UseSwagger();

        ...

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        { 
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });

        ...
    }
```